# Javascript window.open on link isn't working within PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following script located at the top of my web page to open a popup window based on the URL parameter I pass it...

```
<Script Language="JavaScript">
function showDetails(source) {
    window.open(source,"","scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no");
}
</Script>
```

And I have the following PHP code that calls the function to open the window and passes the url...

```
$QueryResult = @$this->DBConnect->query($SQLString);

            if ($QueryResult !== FALSE) {
                if ($QueryResult->num_rows > 0) {       
                    while (($Row = $QueryResult->fetch_assoc())
                                    !== NULL) {
                        echo "<br /><a href='javascript:showDetails(http://server/~user/PHP/EventDetails.php?PHPSESSID=".session_id()."&EventID=".$Row['EventID'].")'>".
                                htmlentities($Row['Title'])."</a>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</td>";

                if ((($FirstDOW + $i) % 7) == 0) {
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
```

When I hover over the link on the web page the URL passed to the function looks fine, and I see something like this at the bottom of the browser, however, when I click the link it does nothing...

```
javascript:showDetails(http://server/~user/PHP/EventDetails.php?PHPSESSID=Hij3234Abdc732hlae&EventID=2)
```

Comment: Are you aware that your url must be a string, and string need to be quoted in javascript?

Comment: You need quotes around the url. javascript has no idea what `http://...` is, but does know that `'http://...'` (note the `'` quotes) is a string...

Comment: `Language` attribute on script element (and that in itself spelled capitalized), still using `href="javascript:"` instead of unobtrusive event handling … so just out of curiosity: _Which century have thou traveled from to our’s, my strange friend …?_

Comment: @CBroe, I don't think you need to span century boundaries to visit times where these techniques were quite common. ;)

Comment: @CBroe considering this is some of my first exposure to Javascript/PHP  programming and I simply don't have the time to explore more efficient methods at this time, I think this will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error.

```
echo "<br /><a href='javascript:showDetails(\"http://server/~user/PHP/EventDetails.php?PHPSESSID=".session_id()."&EventID=".$Row['EventID']."\")'>".htmlentities($Row['Title'])."</a>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You normally put strings in quotes, like

```
echo "<br /><a href='javascript:showDetails(\"http://server/~user/PHP/EventDetails.php?PHPSESSID="
    .session_id()."&EventID=".$Row['EventID']."\")'>".
                            htmlentities($Row['Title'])."</a>";
```